# AngularJS Directive is not linking when using an input in the template to replace an input in the html with the type attribute specified

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm having a really specific, strange issue.

We have to code our app to support IE8.  We are wrapping the Angular-Bootstrap's Typeahead directive in a template to encapsulate a lookup widget with some extra functionality.

The issue we're having is that our directive template looks like this:

```
'<input ng-model="typeaheadValue" typeahead="xxx.code as formatXxx(xxx) for xxx in searchXxxs($viewValue)">'
```

Inside the link function in the directive we are simply calling replace: true and passing in some values to the scope.

This works beautifully in both IE8 and Chrome.

Now, the REALLY strange part is that, for IE8 only, if we say in the HTML in which we're using the directive:

```
<input type="text" search-directive>
```

It will not ever get into the link function.  If i take the type="text" off everything works perfectly.

I created a simple JSFiddle to mimic what we're doing with a really basic test.  Unfortunately for me the JSFiddle doesn't work in IE8 - but this is basically what we're doing. This can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/lungsponge121/8xGuF/ (this is my first fiddle, not sure if it's editable or not)

After fighting with it for hours I've found the following: if i keep the html as (input type="text") and i replace the directive template input element with label or textarea it works fine, but when i use input it does not work at all.  I also removed all of the typeahead code from the template and found that in IE8 it still doesn't work.  The IE8 console did nothing for me and just gave me the standard illegal operation.undefined error.

I had somebody I work with help me debug my code and right now we're wondering if this is a bug.  Has anybody else run into this - I'm thinking of submitting this to the Angular people as I can't find out how to get around this.

Answer (score 1):

One thing jumped out at me: your directive is doing replace. The markup of the template you are replacing it with does not have the type="text", whereas the original markup does. I have noticed that replace does a sort of merge, and it may be getting confused when trying to merge or replace some HTML that has an attribute with a template that does not.

Interestingly, you don't really need to replace the original markup with a template at all. That is one use of directives, but not the most powerful in my opinion. Take "replace" off and remove the template entirely, if you're just trying to extend the typeahead anyway. In my own projects, for example, I might put several different directives attributes on a single element and they all add their own flavor of extra functionality to the existing element. All of them have a reference to the same $element, you just have to be careful that they don't conflict.

I wrote the rest of this before I looked at the fiddle first, sorry.

I'm on a chromebook so I can't test the IE8 thing, but if I recall IE is very picky about HTML attributes. Have you tried any of the following:

- [Alternate directive specification](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive), as in data-search-directive
- Make sure the directive has a property, as in search-directive="", even if you don't use it
- Is the template cache really necessary? Have you tried this just by putting the template in a template property of the directive?
- Is IE8 happy without "use strict"?
- Have you seen the [angular ui bootstrap alternative typeahead](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead)? At the very least, looking at what they did may give you ideas of how to do what you are trying to do.