# Multiple attribute and values dynamic in Angularjs from Jade template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, pug

I have Jade template to templatize HTML content and AngularJS passing the values from Controller (via `$scope`)

Angular Tag name is

```
ngtagname attr1=value1 attr2=value2 attr3=value3 
etc.. until
attr20=value20 ngtagname
```

And these attribute count is growing and these attributes are optional in nature, I have decided to bring only one combined angular value `{{completeValue}}` (combining both attributes and value) from Controller (via `$scope`)  and hence the output will be anything like

```
ngtagname attr5=value5 attr7=value7  ngtagname (OR)
ngtagname attr11=value11 attr15=value15 attr18=value18  ngtagname (OR)
some other combination..
```

This is to avoid lengthy if / unless conditions and validations that are not flexible in Jade

Assuming that `$scope.tag_attributes` is the variable from Angular, I tried the following in Jade but none of them worked to the output required.

JADE

```
"{{tag_attributes}}"
```

HTML

```
{{tag_attributes}}="{{tag_attributes}}"
```

Resulting output error

```
Error: Failed to execute 'setAttribute' on 'Element': '{{tag_attributes}}' is not a valid attribute name.
```

JADE

```
"{{tag_attributes}}"=""
```

HTML

```
{{tag_attributes}}=""
```

**Resulting output error**

```
No Error & attributes are not considered for angular usage
```

Now with another approach / suggestions 
  from A) Trying out http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/#and-attributes
  from B) As well [Pass an object to angularjs template from jade](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759927/pass-an-object-to-angularjs-template-from-jade)

put the details in the plunker
  http://plnkr.co/edit/T0JkSK6iybKBHhkGdlfL?p=preview

Objective is to pass the $scope.attrib value into the JADE which is waiting for additional attributes from $scope.attrib.

So, can anyone just fix the current Plunkr's code line number 13, that would be great.

|my-directive(two="test3")&attributes(#{attrib})

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I can understand that for conditional Attribute and its Value, itself, we can use http://thoughts.amphibian.com/2014/04/conditional-attributes-with-jade.html But don't want to put 20 conditions... in my case. So, continuing my research and your help seeking ..

Comment: Thinking about this .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844317/angularjs-directive-is-not-linking-when-using-an-input-in-the-template-to-replac?rq=1

Comment: why wouldn't you make an array and assign the values you want to pass as elements in the array?  or, make an object and set the properties of the object as the properties you want to pass to the directive?

Comment: Hello Claies, Unfortunately, these are third party directives and I don't want to modify them.. But as per one friend suggestion , trying out http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/#and-attributes

Comment: Based on
   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25759927/pass-an-object-to-angularjs-template-from-jade
In the controller, 
'code' var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg"}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
$scope.userData = jsontext;
 as well as 
$scope.userData =  contact;
$log.log("In controller userData ", $scope.userData ); 'code'
In the jade program.. 
      script.
        setTimeout(function(){ 
        var data = !{JSON.stringify(userData)}
        console.log("angularData ",data) }, 1000);

Comment: In the **html** program
         <script>
            setTimeout(function(){ 
            var data = 
            console.log("angularData ",data) }, 1000);
         </script>

Yep, the data doesn't have any angular assignment as per the JADE2HTML convertor.. 
In the console 

In controller userData  {"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg"}

 angularData  **undefined**

I am unable to get AngularJS userData into this JADE variable Can you please suggest me any other options? thanks .

Comment: if you are trying to clarify your question, can you edit the question and post the code there rather than in comments? aside from being almost unreadable in comments like that, comments aren't guaranteed to be seen by people browsing the question.

Comment: Thanks Claies for the good suggestion. Will edit the question. Yes. ITs difficult to keep more details in the comments.